# Select only numeric value

Tags: sql, oracle, integer

I have a table structure like below.

```
id            version     REQ_REF_ID
 3              1.2            6
 2              1.1            6
 1               1             6
```

My query  is below

`Select * from XYZ where REQ_REF_ID = 6606 order by version desc FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY`

It gives me the latest 2 rows which id is 3 and 2.

But I want to get only those two row where `version` number is integer, not having decimal values.

In this case I want to get the row which id is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check against [ROUND](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm) function to get integer values

```
and ROUND(version) = version
```

> ROUND returns n rounded to integer places to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: @Patel did you test with `round(1.0)`?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber `1.0` is a *whole number* and therefore `round(1.0) = 1.0`

Comment: @user7294900 simple test with  following data `1.0,  1.0,  1`. The `round` can't distinct them so you get some random result.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `TRANSLATE`

```
 where translate(VERSION, '?1234567890', '?') is null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check like

```
and (version)%1 = 0
```

% by 1 will give you decimal parts if any